# Redirect a wix website page to external URL

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a wix page which will redirect all users that link to it to an external URL.

I tried adding the code below as a "html wix app" but it didn't worked.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.my-new-url.com">
```

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar use case and solved it using the wix-location module:

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'; 

$w.onReady(function () {
     wixLocation.to("http://www.my-new-url.com");
})
```

Comment: Great ,  this is works fine .It is based on the wixcode API . How to use it : open the page you`re editing . click on the code panel and paste the code .Just like that and publish it. Everything works as expected .

Comment: @DaggieBlanqx - does this method yield a 301 status code, or something different?

Comment: @optimus203 no , it doesnt yield 301 status code -  since its client-side redirection

Comment: This waits for the page to load fully and then does a redirection. Is there a way to redirect without waiting for the whole page to load?

Comment: any way to make a 301 redirect?

Comment: You can make a 301 redirect according to the support article here: https://support.wix.com/en/article/setting-up-a-301-redirect-for-a-page-on-your-site

Answer (score 3):

When you insert an HTML "module" into Wix, it is actually inserted into an iframe on the page rather than the page itself.

Fortunately, the iframe is hosted at the same domain, so you don't have to deal with cross-domain issues. Therefore, this code, when inserted into an HTML module on a Wix page, successfully redirects the parent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.location.href = "http://www.my-new-url.com"
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work even though it seems to make sense. What should I do?

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf It is currently working for me on a live site: http://www.baseballforall.com.

Comment: wow, love this site even though I don't know if you made it by yourself or using Wix. When I try your code into my Wix site it get's disabled for some reason. I don't have premium

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wix-location](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-location.html) from [Wix Code](https://www.wix.com/code/home), for this. An example of using it to navigate to an external URL is:

```js
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

// ...

wixLocation.to("http://www.my-new-url.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.my-new-url.com/" />
```

You left out a " at the end.
I hope this helps!

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://www.my-new-url.com"
</script>
```

Try this:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.my-new-url.com/" />
</html>
```

Comment: chrome. What code exactly did you added to the wix html app? Did it redirected you to the the external link or just opened it in a frame ?

Comment: It just opens it in a frame inside the page. I want the page to be redirected to the given URL.

BTW, I'm trying to redirect it to a Google Play URL.

Comment: Do you want it to open the playstore app or...?

Comment: No. Just a Play Store link
eg. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp

Comment: Is it on mobile or pc?

Comment: Your new edit is not working for https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

The above code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.location.href = "http://www.my-new-url.com"
</script>
```

works on my wix site:
https://www.lemon-sin.com.au/
redirects to director's linkedin account